# Using Azure key vault in Kubernetes deployment file

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cicd

I've configure ci/cd pipeline for my webapp application. There is nothing extraordinary. Build and push for docker hub then apply k8s deployment on Azure Kubernetes Service.
Everthign works finde but I store env variables in `deployment.yaml` file directly which is not safe because there are db connection strings.
Configuring Azure Pipeline I can use Azure Key Vault which is not a problem but how i can pass these key-value to my Kubernetes deployment?

Basiccally in my `deployment.yaml` I'd love to have something like this :

```
  env:
  - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
    value: ${Development_variableFromAzure}
  - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
    value: ${URLS_variableFromAzure}
```

Comment: you should have a look at helm charts: https://helm.sh/

Answer (score 1):

To securely inject environment variables from Azure Key Vault into your Kubernetes deployment, you can enable the Azure Key Vault provider for the Secrets Store CSI Driver as an add-on in your AKS cluster.

Firstly, enable the Azure Key Vault provider add-on for your AKS cluster using Azure CLI:

```
 az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name <clustername> --resource-group <resourcegroupname>
```

[image]

This command will set up the Azure Key Vault provider for the Secrets Store CSI Driver in your AKS cluster and create a user-assigned managed identity for authentication with Azure Key Vault.
Next, assign the necessary permissions to the managed identity created by the add-on to access your Azure Key Vault:
[image]

```
az keyvault set-policy -n <yourkeyvaultname> --secret-permissions get --spn <'clientIDwhichyouwillgetfromtheoutputoftheabovecommand'>
```

[image]

Define a `SecretProviderClass` resource in your Kubernetes cluster to reference the Azure Key Vault and the specific secrets.

```yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: my-azure-kv
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    keyvaultName: "YourKeyVaultName"
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: Development-variableFromAzure
          objectType: secret
        - |
          objectName: URLs-variableFromAzure
          objectType: secret
    tenantId: "YourTenantId/DirectoryIDofAzureVault"
```

Modify your `deployment.yaml` to use the SecretProviderClass and reference the secrets as environment variables

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-front
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
        env:
        - name: azure-vote-front_ENVIRONMENT
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: my-azure-kv
              key: Development-variableFromAzure
        - name: azure-vote-front_URLS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: my-azure-kv
              key: URLs-variableFromAzure
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-azure-kv-volume
          mountPath: /mnt/secrets-store
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: my-azure-kv-volume
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "my-azure-kv"
```

Your application can now access these environment variables as it normally would. The secrets are injected into the pod from Azure Key Vault and are not exposed in your deployment manifests.
[image]

[image]

Just ensure your [Azure Pipeline is configured to have the necessary permissions to access the Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/key-vault-in-own-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=portal).

Reference Documents:

[Use Azure KV in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/key-vault-in-own-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=portal)

[Use Azure KV for Secret Store CSI Driver in AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver)

Comment: `az keyvault set-policy ` I'm getting error `Cannot set policies to a vault with '--enable-rbac-authorization' specified`. I've set key vaul admin on key vault. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah that's because your vault is using RBAC settings, go to your keyvault and on left side under setting there is 'access configuration', when you click on that you will see currently it is set to rbac and below that there is vault access policy, click on vault access policy, tick mark all the resource access and apply and then come back and retry your command, it will work

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't marked it as answer yet because i could'nt test it fully. I hope I'll finish it soon. But i have onemore question. Can we use key vault secret in k8s deployment like for container image or k8s namespace?